# AWS assumed-role unable to perform secretsmanager:GetSecretValue in serverless project

Tags: amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a serverless project written with node.js.

This service defines an IAM role for use at runtime with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        // statement to allow logging omitted
        // statement for VPC stuff omitted (CreateNetworkInterface, etc)
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:*:secret:my_secret_name-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a lambda that then tries to read that secrets:

```
import SecretsManager from 'aws-sdk/clients/secretsmanager' // v2

...

export const handler: ValidatedEventAPIGatewayProxyEvent<typeof schema> = async (event, context: any) => {
  try {
    const sm = new SecretsManager({ region }) // region is defined as "eu-west-1"
    const secret = await sm.getSecretValue({
      SecretId: 'my_secret_name'
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
```

This errors with the following:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::{accountId}:assumed-role/my-service-lambda-role/my-service-my-stage-my-function is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
```

I'm not sure why the permissions would not allow me to retrieve the secret. I'm further not sure why this is using `sts` and using an `assumed-role` rather than just using the serverless lambda role directly. Can someone explain this to me and how to fix this?

NOTE: using the [policysimulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#roles), I can confirm the role created with the above policy *does* have access to read the defined secret, so this *must* be to do with assumed roles?